# Successful response from Super Stack API but account not charged

Tags: transactions

I'm currently testing Super Stack integration with my website. When I first visit the website I can see that the transaction is successful.  The second time I visit the transaction also seems successful but there is no record in my transaction log and my account was not debited. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super Stack does not allow two transactions within a given time window. Therefore, only the first transaction gets recorded. The second transaction is skipped, but the API considers this successful.